# Spinning in docker nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, server, localhost, docker-image

I have been revolving around the nginx with docker . Eventually I created a docker image for four servers and ran from the docker container to ports 5500,5600,5700,5800 smoothly . Then I tried to connect these servers to nginx for practicing the load balancing , the problem is that when I used nginx container the server context is located on default.config file where it is part of config.d directory

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /nginx_statu{
            stub_status;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }
}
```

and the http context is located in the nginx.config file which appears as

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
     
        }
server {

                    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

          error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html; }
        }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
 include /etc/nginx/config.d/deault.config

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
}
```

When I checked the logs of the nginx server it shows error like this

```
# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>An error occurred.</h1>
<p>Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.<br/>
Please try again later.</p>

<p>If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check
the error log for details.</p>
<p><em>Faithfully yours, nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyhow I managed to solve the problem with downloading native nginx for windows and configured the nginx.conf which looks pretty working as a fine one, I think that there may be the issues in the official docker image regarding to that defining nginx.conf as the nginx directories seems to be messy . Is my view is an actual scenerio or the error is within me . Correct me if I am wrong .